# " compile timeout " error on beamer class

Tags: beamer

I am making a presentation using \documentclass{beamer}. Moreover, I am making it at overleaf.com

My presentation has a lot of high resolution images, which are in .png format, because of which I am getting " compile timeout " error. I looked into online help and found this

https://www.overleaf.com/help/46-why-do-i-keep-getting-the-compile-timeout-error-message#.VbVZ_1Y7Q_s

Everything for me is in png format and I want to keep it like that. How can I get around this problem?

Comment: Since this seems to be an overleaf problem, why don't you ask in overleaf? That seems to be the natural place to ask in this case. In the link you provided, under **Still Stuck?** they say "If you have a compile timeout error that you cannot resolve, please let us know and we'll take a look for you." and they provide a contact link.

Comment: Is there any reason that you do not install tex and run the document locally? tex itself has no time limits, it does not seem unreasonable that overleaf restricts the usage of each individual job that is running on their servers, but that is unrelated to tex, really.

Comment: Actually I am using one of the templates available at overleaf.com so didn't try it at tex. Found that more convenient but may be it was true only for small presentations .

Comment: In my experience, Overleaf is painfully slow even for small, simple documents. So even if it doesn't timeout, I would think it would be a whole lot less frustrating to compile locally. With a lot of PNGs, even *that* can be painful. But I hate to think what it would be like on Overleaf :(.

Comment: Since I am an enduser kind of person, and didn't experiment a lot with tex stuff, so I found overleaf easy since it provided with templates. I think that is why I have been avoiding local solutions

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue with a large report I wrote on overleaf also.

Adding the ".PNG" to the file name when including it, substantially reduced the compile time also..